# Learn Web services in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I am new to Java web service and need to be familiar with REST and SOAP based web service for my project.

Can you please refer any book or any online tutorial link regarding it?

Comment: I did google it first but found it confusing..didn't get any good link that can be helpful for newbie

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but I have found that its easiest to try building a small prototype then expand it when I need ot learn something.

Comment: The first link from googling 'rest web service' pulls up a wikipedia page, which is extremely helpful.  Perhaps you should get into more detail.  What don't you understand about Rest/Soap?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you have two things to learn:

1. **Service design of RESTful web services**: What makes a web service RESTful? What design decisions should you take or avoid when designing a REST service? REST services should be implementation agnostic; When you're designing a REST service, you shouldn't need to worry about whether you're going to implement it in Ruby or Java or whatever else. I recommend the [O'Reilly Cookbook](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFoQFjAB&url=http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do&ei=5iDiT_fEDYWo8ATWy7yGCA&usg=AFQjCNFtmJ7c7pweE0xYM64_WdQNA6pRLQ).
2. **How Do I implement a RESTful web service?** If you need to use java, you'll want to evaluate a few different frameworks to decide what's right for you. I've outlined a few below.

[Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) is quite a popular java REST framework that has been around a while.

[Spring REST](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html) might work well if you're already using Spring in other areas.

I haven't used [DropWizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/), but it seems really cool. If you're looking for something pretty lightweight, I'd start here.

In terms of SOAP, from a java perspective [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) is certainly quite popular. You don't say in your question whether or not you need a single service to support both SOAP and REST, but if you do, Axis2 will [kinda do this](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/rest-ws.html).